# Serializing Response Inside A Class As A List

Tags: c#, .net, rest, .net-core

I'm trying to fetch Symptoms from an API. I can fetch them already and I'm serializing it inside a class succesfully. The result looks like in image that i share at below:
[image: Symptoms Response]

There are just IDs and Names inside them. The second table from API is like that:
[image: SymptomsInBodySubLocation]

So here my Entity Class;

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SymptomousInBodySublocations
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool HasRedFlag { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BodyLocations> HealthSymptomLocationIDs { get; set; }
    public string ProfName { get; set; }
    public List<string> Synonyms { get; set; }
}
```

And my Serialize Method:

```
public static List<SymptomousInBodySublocations> SymptomsInBodySublocations()
{
    var client = new RestClient("https://priaid-symptom-checker-v1.p.rapidapi.com/symptoms/31/man?format=json&language=en-gb");
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.AddHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "priaid-symptom-checker-v1.p.rapidapi.com");
    request.AddHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "<api-key>");
    List<SymptomousInBodySublocations> SymptomsInBodySublocationsList = new List<SymptomousInBodySublocations>();
     var response = client.Execute<List<SymptomousInBodySublocations>>(request);
     foreach(SymptomousInBodySublocations variables in response.Data)
     {
         SymptomsInBodySublocationsList.Add(variables);
     } 
      return SymptomsInBodySublocationsList;
}
```

And my BodyLocations Class:

```
public class BodyLocations
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In this point when i tried to fetch my data inside my `List<BodyLocations>()` the `response.Data` is empty. What should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HealthSymptomLocationIDs isn't an object, looking at the response it is an array of integers.

Changing the field to match the response should populate the field with the integer values from the API

`public List<int> HealthSymptomLocationIDs { get; set; }`